# Validating form with Jquery and without validate.js file

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am trying to implement validation with jquery. But do not know where I am doing wrong. Below is my code. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
})
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        txt: {
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txt: {
            required: "Enter your text",
            minLength: "At least 2 characters are necessary",
        }
    }
});
</script>
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Input" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="sbmt" value="Submit Button" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Without `validate.js`? The function `.validate()` is present only there!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I know first i was using validate.js file, then i removed because i am trying to implement validation without using that file. I am messed up here in my code i know. I just shared it. Can you please tell me  that the way which i am trying, is it possible or not? If yes then how?

Comment: Have a look at mine!

Answer (score 1):

Converting your script to manual, we get this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
  if ($(this).find("#rules").val().trim().length < 2) {
    alert("Rules length should be at least 2");
    return false;
  }
  if ($(this).find("#messages").val().trim().length < 2) {
    alert("Messages length should be at least 2");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code may be it helps you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        txt: {
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txt: {
            required: "Enter your text",
            minLength: "At least 2 characters are necessary",
        }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It wont work. Because I do not want to use validate.js file. And if i use .validate() then validate.js file is needed.

Comment: obvious validate.js needed .. otherwise you have to do it manualy

Comment: Manually? How? I want to know any way to make it happen but not using validate.js file.

Comment: and use jquery syntex instand of javascript syntex.

Comment: [Syntex tank](http://1.imimg.com/data/S/6/MY-1184404/sintex-20make-20water-20tanks_10512541_250x250.jpg)? In stand? What stand? `:D`